# Where can I get the twilio-client sdk version 1.2

Tags: sdk, webrtc, twilio, voip

Not sure that this question belongs on Stack Overflow, however I am not sure where else to put it.

We have recently integrated webrtc into one of our projects.  It has just now come to my attention that the javascript library we are using

```
//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.3/twilio.min.js
```

does not support Safari.  According to [this document](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-client/which-browsers-support-webrtc).  I should be able to use version 1.2 of the sdk to use a `flash` fallback.

I have been unable to locate version 1.2, does anybody have a link to it?

I have searched through twilio's github repositories without luck.  Any google link I have found is dead and outdated.  Switching the library url to 1.2 or any other iteration does not work either

Thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 1):

For future readers. I was able to find the file here

```
//static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js
```

However, I have not had any success actually getting it working with Flash in Safari.